# How can I know if tail call optimisation is occurring

Tags: javascript, optimization, ecmascript-6

I have been cleaning some code and and have tail call optimisation as one of the things to make modifications to code so that I can get the advantage of the performance improvement.

Is there a way on one of the browser's (dev tools) to see if tail call optimisation is occurring so that I can get some feedback on it's finer details as I am still a little unsure in some situations. Or should it appear on the call stack (ie drops the calling function from the stack if its a tail call) or have I no optimisation occurring at all, as I see nothing like that on Chrome and Firefox??

Comment: Can you include `javascript` at Question?

Comment: Try [https://benchmarkjs.com/](https://benchmarkjs.com)

Comment: AFAIK tco is not implemented in any browsers yet: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: @AlexanderMac thanks but not what I am looking for.

Comment: @DavinTryon Ok I have been misinformed, just checked (should have done befor the question) and none of the browsers have tail call optimisation. Guess that is why I don't see anything, Oh well no harm in having code ready for it. Thanks

Comment: If you transpile with babel, you get some tco (I think).  Might be an option depending on you setup.

Comment: @Davin TCO is removed in Babel 6 (temporarily, in theory).